# Using Phonegap plugins no eclipse

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using: build.phonegap.com or the commandline version through node.js.

Platform: all supported by Phonegap, i am not asking for 1 specific, however i do develop mostly for Android.

This is a question about posibilities.

Ive been working with Phonegap for some month now, but i never used Eclipse.

I use this: http://phonegap.com/install/

After running the commands as described in the above link i will get a libary like this:

- myApp

  - .cordova
  - merges
  - platforms
  - plugins
  - www

The "www" folder has all the normal things like

- css
- img
- js
- re
- spec
- config.xml
- icon.png
- index.html
- spec.html

As long as i use the inbuild functionalities from phonegap.com eg. geolocation, storage, camera and media, everything works great.  I can access that through 100% pure javascript APIs.  I dont have to add anything extra to the libary.

**Using phonegap plugins**

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using

I tried everything i can think of.  I cant get any of the plugins to work.

Im thinking that i really need to get eclipse to use those plugins?

So my question is really all about, can i use those plugins, if i continue to work as i do, or do i need to get eclipse in order to get it working?

**important!**
I can use the normal integrated APIs already camera, geolocation ect ect.

Comment: eg. if i wanted to use a speecs plugin i see many use eclipse to place a speed.java file, to enable that kinda funktionality.

Comment: I hava the same "problem", i would like to avoid eclipse to compile my cordova / phonegap application with plugins like "QR code scanner or facebook auth" ... I don't find how to link any .jar to the project. Have you solved your problem? Thx!

Comment: Daniel , you solved this ? I have same problem , any input from you will be help full.